# 3D Polyline by Slope on Surface

Tags: dem, line, slope

I wish to project (continue/extend/whatever) a polyline upslope following a specified gradient along a DEM surface. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? An algorithm? A procedure using your favorite GIS software (which software)?  What format should the output have?  Also, what do you mean by a "specified gradient"? After all, the DEM already stipulates where the surface is (in 3D) and it therefore *determines* the gradient lying over any given polyline: there is nothing left to "specify."

Comment: Thanks for your response - I should have been more specific. I am using Arc 10.1 and I am basically looking for a procedure or set of procedures that would allow me to to perform this sort of operation in arc (http://files.carlsonsw.com/mirror/manuals/Carlson_2013/source/Site_Road_Design/3D_Data/3D_Polyline_by_Slope_on_Surface/3D_Polyline_by_Slope_on_Surface.htm)